# Cannot GET the requested API in express.js

Tags: mysql, http, express, get

Here is my express app code

```
app.get('/books',function(req,res){
    var {keyword} =req.query;
    connection.query('SELECT * from books', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        for(let result of results){
            if(result.title === keyword){
                res.send(result);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and the url i am requesting is http://......../books/keyword=intro. Where `intro` is the user input.

What i am trying to achieve here, is from an input in HTML, to take that info and send it to my API, so it can query my DB and get what i want.

But i get a 404 error, so i guess my api is configured incorrectly.

Is there a better way to implement what i am doing?

Is the `keyword=intro` even the correct way to query my db.

My html is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
</head>




<body>
    <div id="data"> 
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Click"/>
        <input type="text" id="search" >
    </div>
    <div id="search">

    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',getUserInput);
        function getUserInput(event){
            var userInput = document.getElementById("search").value;
            if(userInput !== ""){
                httpGetAsync(userInput);
            }
        }

        function httpGetAsync(searchTerm){
            var theUrl = 'books?keyword=' + searchTerm;
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
            xhttp.send(null);
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

            function processRequest() {

                if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE);
                var result = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
                console.log(result);
        }}

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Your URL syntax is wrong - try `http://<server>:<port>/books?keyword=intro` (last `/` changed to `?`). Also, you might want to hide your server IP.

Comment: FYI, you should NEVER have `if (error) throw error;` inside an async callback on your server.  That is never acceptable error handling for a server.  Write code that actually deals with errors - probably something like `console.log(err); res.sendStatus(500); return`.

Comment: @Vasan changed ip and `/` into `?` but i still get a 404

Comment: @ChristopherBovo Try removing the `/` at the end of your route : `app.get('/books'`. Also, where is your middleware that handles 404 placed? Is it placed after all (valid) route middlewares?

Comment: @Vasan i did what you suggested yet i still get a 404. I currently do not have a middleware for 404 errors

Comment: How are you displaying the HTML? Is it hosted on node as static file? Or is it rendered from templating engine? Can you post the full node code? I tried a fragment of your code before the `connection.query` part and it gives me a 200 with the keyword in body (as expected) and not a 404, once I corrected the URL as mentioend in my comment.

Comment: @Vasan so what i did was, in HTML i removed the `/` and replaced it with `?`, thus becoming `'books?keyword='`. This way i got it working.Will update the post with the code

Answer (score 1):

In httpGetAsync function replace

```
var theUrl = 'books/keyword=' + searchTerm;
```

with:

```
var theUrl = window.location + '/books/keyword=' + searchTerm;
```

Comment: This is actually wrong because it would append `/books/...` to current full URL (which might have filename at the end).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more of a comment unless it's acceptable. The statement that I want to write is too long for a comment.

In regards to my answer is that a valid way to write your prepared statement model? How I write my SQL models are like this and it works fine. Are you receiving any errors from your SQL syntax?

Notice the brackets after the `?`.

```js
    selectBooks: function(data, callback) {
        let keyword = "%" + req.query + "%";
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE ?", [keyword], callback);
    }
```